# How can I set an HTTP proxy on a WCF server side?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

How can I set an HTTP proxy on a WCF server side?

Is there is any way for that ?

Comment: i need to set a proxy external to the country which have the server.

Answer (score 2):

You use a proxy server when you need to access some resource that is not on the same network as the client and for which the client has no direct access. Is your web service accessing remote resources like for example web pages? If on the other hand you are having issues calling your service then you need to set the proxy on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

specify the proxy settings in web.config file

```
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true">
            <proxy proxyaddress="http://yourproxyserver:proxyport"/>
        </defaultProxy>     
    </system.net>
```